# AppleScript does not understand "ApplicationIsRunning" message

Tags: applescript

I am new to AppleScript and trying to incorporate a script associated with the logging out of my VPN. Basically, if my VPN fails or I log out, I want it to close my browser for security purposes. However, Applescript won't "understand" the ApplicationIsRunning check that I have found everywhere online... any thoughts??

```
set apps to {"Firefox", "uTorrent"}
repeat with thisApp in apps
    if ApplicationIsRunning(thisApp) then
        tell application thisApp to quit
    end if
end repeat
```

Error:

```
error "«script» doesn’t understand the “ApplicationIsRunning” message." number -1708 from «script»
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```applescript
set apps to {"Firefox", "uTorrent"}
repeat with thisApp in apps
  if application thisApp is running then
    tell application thisApp to quit
  end if
end repeat
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.